# Installing Spyder in a conda environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, spyder, virtual-environment

I have created a `conda` environment for `qcodes` using the Anaconda prompt as follows,

```
conda create -n qcodes
conda activate qcodes
conda config --add channels conda-forge --env
conda config --set channel_priority strict --env
conda install qcodes
```

As Spyder isn't in the environment I tried to install using,

```
conda install spyder
```

Which gives me the following error,

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - python=3.1
```

I tried to update `conda` using,

```
conda update conda
```

and got...

```
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Users\nr2-roberts\.conda\envs\qcodes
  package name: conda
```

I get the same with `conda update anaconda`

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Seems like you have python 3.10 in you `qcodes` env. There is not (for the moment) Spyder packages on conda (neither on the default channel or the conda-forge channel) compatibale with Python 3.10. I would suggest you to recreate your env but when doing `conda install qcodes` do `conda install qcodes python=3.9`

Comment: @DanielAlthviz that was it, if you want to put your comment as an answer to the problem, I can then uptick & accept it to make it easier for others to find in the future

Comment: Sure @DrBwts, done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you have python 3.10 in your qcodes env. There is not (for the moment) Spyder packages on conda (neither on the default channel or the conda-forge channel) compatible with Python 3.10. I would suggest you to recreate your env but when doing `conda install qcodes` do `conda install qcodes python=3.9`

**Edit:** Spyder is now available for Python 3.10. However, the default anaconda channel is not up to date with the latest Spyder release/version. Just in case, if you want to use the latest Spyder version you will need to use the conda-forge channel. Also, some links to check the different versions of Spyder available throught the default anaconda and conda-forge channels:

- Default anaconda channel: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spyder/files
- conda-forge channel: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spyder/files